# Writing multiline string of Javascript in Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, escaping

I'm trying to create a string of Javascript using q{} as such:

```
    my $javascript = q{
        $(function () {
            var chart;

            $(document).ready(function () {

                // Build the chart
                $(\'#container\').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: \'title\'
                    },
    };
```

It needs to be in segments like this, rather than complete Javascript blocks.  My problem is that, since the block isn't complete, it contains open brackets '{' without closing brackets and perl is interpreting the closing bracket for q{} as a closing bracket for one of the javascript blocks.  I tried using q() instead, but the same problem occurs.  Can I use another character as a delimiter other than ( or { ?  I also tried using qq but that resulted in the same problem, and it involves more escaping.  I know I can do it without q or qq and just write individual lines, but this looks so much cleaner so I'd like to get this working and I'm sure there must be a way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In single-quoted literals, you must escape `\` and the delimiters (`{` and `}` in this case).

```
q{abc\{def\\ghi'jkl}  # Produces: abc{def\ghi'jkl
```

Exception: You need not escape `\` if it unambiguous.

```
q{abc\\def}    # Produces: abc\def
q{abc\def}     # Produces: abc\def, just like previous

q{abc\\\\def}  # Produces: abc\\def
q{abc\\\def}   # Produces: abc\\def, just like previous
```

Exception: You need not the delimiters if you are using `{}`, `[]` or `()` the delimiters are balanced in the literal.

```
q{ foo \{ bar \{ baz \} qux \} moo }   # Produces:  foo { bar { baz } qux } moo 
q{ foo \{ bar { baz } qux \} moo }     # Same as above
q{ foo { bar { baz } qux } moo }       # Same as above
```

The problem is that you didn't properly escape your delimiters. You also expected `\'` to result in `'` when it results in `\'`.

```
my $javascript = q{
    $(function () \{                          <---- Escape
        var chart;

        $(document).ready(function () \{      <---- Escape

            // Build the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({      <---- No slash for ', and
                chart: {                            optional for balanced { }
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'title'
                },
};
```

Better yet, use a delimiter that does not appear in the text. (You'd only have to escape `\\`.)

```
my $javascript = q~
    $(function () {
        var chart;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Build the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'title'
                },
~;
```

Another option is to use a single-quoted heredoc. You need not — indeed you cannot — escape anything.

```
my $javascript = <<'__EOJS__';
    $(function () {
        var chart;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Build the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'title'
                },
__EOJS__
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a different delimiter like `q~ ~`

```
    my $javascript = q~
        $(function () {
            var chart;

            $(document).ready(function () {

                // Build the chart
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'title'
                    },
    ~;
```

Or use a heredoc:

```
    my $javascript = <<'END_JS';
        $(function () {
            var chart;

            $(document).ready(function () {

                // Build the chart
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'title'
                    },
END_JS
```

Note: I translated all `\'` to just `'` in the above text, as they were likely an artifact from using single quotes as your delimiter originally.

Comment: Using the heredoc works well.  I tried multiple other delimiters and they didn't work...I tried ~, *, %, \, etc.  Any reason why they wouldn't work?

Comment: If they were used like I demonstrated above `q~ ~` and your actual text matched your example, then there is no reason why an alternative delimiter wouldn't work.  You would want to pick a delimiter that wasn't included in your text ideally.  '~` is probably the most common choice.  However, if all you have is literal text, a heredoc is your best choice in my opinion.

Comment: Looks like it was working, I'm using VIM and the colors change for strings, etc. and when I use a delimiter like ~ the colors change as if it was strings and variables.  However when I compile, it runs correctly.  Just unpleasant to look at.  I think I'll stick with the heredoc.  Thanks!